# Santa Fe xeric indigenous tree

Tags: species-identification, botany, trees

The hills around [Santa Fe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santa_Fe,_New_Mexico) are covered in a particular xeric tree which is quite small and looks like some kind of [juniper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juniper) which I have been unable to identify:

[image: Santa Fe trees]

What is this species?

Comment: Do you have any close-up photos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually figured it out. It is the one-seed juniper, [Juniperus monosperma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juniperus_monosperma).